# I want to load data using firebase adapter based on location and opening and closing time

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My firebase database structure is :

[image]

I want to load restaurant based on location and opening and closing time. How should I create database structure ?

```
 FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Restaurant> options=new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Restaurant>()
        .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child("Restaurants").child("")
                ,Restaurant.class).build();


FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Restaurant,RestaurantViewHolder>  adapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Restaurant, RestaurantViewHolder>(options) {
    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RestaurantViewHolder viewHolder, final int position, @NonNull final Restaurant model) {
```

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property, but I'm not sure if that is the case with your opening and closing times, nor with a location, which requires using GeoFire. For an example of what **is** possible, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Can you share example Java code ?

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data and https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java. There is no pre-baked solution that combines them, so you will have to come up with your own adapter for that.

Comment: I think I should create child before 01, 02, 03...